# C++ std::set comparator

Tags: c++, set, comparator, stdset

This is the code:

```
struct comp
{
    bool operator()(Reputation *one, Reputation *two)
    {
        if (one->Amount < 0 && two->Amount >= 0)
            return false;
        if (one->Amount >= 0 && two->Amount < 0)
            return true;

        if (one->Amount >= 0)
            return one->Amount <= two->Amount;
        else
            return one->Amount >= two->Amount;
    }
};
```

And this is the problem:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   File: ..\VC\include\xtree
>   Line: 638
>
> Expression: invalid operator<

After that, I can choose "Abort", "Retry" or "Ignore". If I choose ignore many more (identical ones) come up but it ends up working perfectly.

The problem seems to occur when I insert a Reputation with ->Amount == to one of the Reputation *'s previously inserted, but I'm not sure about this last one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: The order I want them ordered in is first the positive ones in asc order, then the negative ones in desc order. Example: 1 5 10 11 11 20 50 -1 -5 -50

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must define a relation that's **irreflexive**, just like `<` -- therefore, change the `<=` to `<` and the '>=' to '>' in the last couple of comparisons in your method. This is what VC++ is diagnosing.

Moreover, given a correctly coded, `<-`like operator, if two items a and b are such that a < b and b < a are both false, those items are considered equivalent and thus only one will be inserted in the set (it's not material whether the items could be distinguished by some other comparison: only the equivalence relationship implied by the comparator matters).

Comment: Glad I helped fix the "debug assertion failed" issue, but please do read my latest edit about "uniqueness" -- you do need a multiset, like @Kasprzol says, if you want to keep multiple items that are not distinguishable _by the comparator_.

Comment: Yes, I already converted it to a multiset as well following Kasprozl's advice!

Comment: Can you please help me with similar issue? I am unable to resolve it even though the I am getting the same "Debug Assertion Failed!" error with set comparator? link to my question is here:
[link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823469/getting-debug-assertion-failed-for-set-comparator

Answer (score 1):

The items in the `std::set` must be unique! (and less-comparable) If you want to have multiple items with the same value (like the sample you provided) use `std::multiset`.

see: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/set/start and http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/multiset/start

Comment: I converted it to std::multiset, but the same exact problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert same values into std::set, it requires unique values. Use std::multiset.

For your funny ordering this seems to work:

```
struct comp
{
    bool operator()(const Reputation *a, const Reputation *b)
    {
        if (a->Amount < 0 && b->Amount < 0)
            return a->Amount > b->Amount;
        else if (a->Amount < 0) return false;
        else if (b->Amount < 0) return true;
        else return a->Amount < b->Amount;
    }
};
```

Comment: The set is a set of pointers. They are all unique, even if some have the same ->Amount.

This is the exact code:
 multiset<Reputation *, comp> sorted;
 for (Reputation *rep = Reputation::GetReputationTable(); rep->Id; ++rep)
  sorted.insert(rep);

Comment: Oh ok, it wasn't clear from the example ... but yeah if you store pointers use pointers