# Getting "Debug Assertion Failed!" for set comparator

Tags: c++, std

I know similar issue has been answered at this link [Help me fix this C++ std::set comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061152/help-me-fix-this-c-stdset-comparator)
but unfortunately I am facing exactly same issue and I am unable to understand the reason behind it thus need some help to resolve it.

I am using VS2010 and my release binary is running fine without any issue but the debug binary reports:

[image]

My comparator looks like this:

```
struct PathComp {
    bool operator() (const wchar_t* path1, const wchar_t* path2) const
    {
        int c = wcscmp(path1, path2);
        if (c < 0 || c > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

My set is declared like this:

```
set<wchar_t*,PathComp> pathSet;
```

Could somebody suggest me why my debug binary is failing at this assertion? Is it because I am using wcscmp() function to compare the wide character string getting stored in my set?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What's on or around line 960 of xtree?

Comment: @960:

`_Addleft = _DEBUG_LT_PRED(this->comp, this->_Kfn(_Val), this->_Key(_Trynode)); // favor right end`

Answer (score 18):

`std::set` requires a valid comperator that behaves like `operator<` or `std::less`.

The std::set code detected that your operator< is not valid, and as a help to you triggered the assert you showed.

And indeed: your comperator looks like an `operator!=`, not like an `operator<`

One of the rules an `operator<` should follow, is that `a<b` and `b<a` cannot be both true. In your implementation, it is.

Correct your code to:

```
bool operator() (const wchar_t* path1, const wchar_t* path2) const
{  
  int c = wcscmp(path1, path2);
  return (c < 0);
}
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: Beat me to it. Anytime you see `if (x < 0 || x > 0)` I'd be worried about why `if (x != 0)` (or some other form of single direct comparison) wasn't used instead.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that your comparator does not induce a strict-weak ordering. It should only really return true for paths that are "less" - not for all that are different. Change it to:

```
struct PathComp {
    bool operator() (const wchar_t* path1, const wchar_t* path2) const
    {
        int c = wcscmp(path1, path2);
        if (c < 0) {  // <- this is different
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Alternatively, using only `c > 0` will also work - but the set will have a reverse order.

The algorithm needs to know the difference between smaller and greater to work, just unequal does not give enough information.
Without smaller-than/greater-than information, the set cannot possibly maintain an order - but that is what a set is all about.

Answer (score 1):

After spending some more time on it we finally decided to take another approach which worked for me.

So we converted wchar_t* to string using this method:

```
// Converts LPWSTR to string
bool convertLPWSTRToString(string& str, const LPWSTR wStr)
{
    bool b = false;
    char* p = 0;
    int bSize;    
    // get the required buffer size in bytes
    bSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,
        0,
        wStr,-1,
        0,0,
        NULL,NULL);     
    if (bSize > 0) {
        p = new char[bSize];
        int rc = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,
            0,
            wStr,-1,
            p,bSize,
            NULL,NULL);
        if (rc != 0) {
            p[bSize-1] = '\0';
            str = p;
            b = true;
        }
    }
    delete [] p;
    return b;
}
```

And then stored that string in the in the set, by doing this I didn't had to worry about comparing the elements getting stored to make sure that all entries are unique.

```
// set that will hold unique path
set<string> strSet;
```

So all I had to do was this:

```
string str;
convertLPWSTRToString(str, FileName);
// store path in the set
strSet.insert(str);
```

Though I still don't know what was causing "Debug Assertion Failed" issue when I was using `a set comparator (PathComp) for set<wchar_t*,PathComp> pathSet;`

Comment: @Vivart This is not an answer actually, that's an work around we followed to solve the issue. So I am still looking for someone to answer the reason behind "Debug Assertion Failed" in the question asked. :-)

Comment: Why on Earth do you convert to UTF-8 instead of simply storing `std::wstring` in the map? It has exactly the same features as `std::string` (in fact it's different specialization of the same `basic_string` template), but based on wchar_t.

Comment: Oh, an why do you allocate temporary buffer on the heap? You can simply `str.resize(bSize)` the string to make it allocate it's buffer and format directly to `&str[0]` (and str.resize(bSize - 1) to trim the `\0` from the end, because `std::string` may contain `\0` bytes.